# Why is my connection of a NodeJS server (Sails) to another NodeJS Server (Express4) using Socket.IO failing?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

I am trying to connect my Node.JS (written using Sails.JS) app to another Node.JS server (Express4 / Socket.io) using `socket.io-client`.

My Sails Service `app/services/Watcher.js` looks like

```
var client = require('../../node_modules/sails/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client');

// callback of the form function(socket)
exports.connect = function(callback) {
  sails.log.debug("will connect socket to", sails.config.watcher.uri, "with Socket.io-client version", client.version);
  var socket = client.connect(sails.config.watcher.uri);
  socket.on('connect', function(){
    sails.log.debug("connected");
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
      sails.log.debug("Disconnected");
    });
    socket.on('error', function(err){
      sails.log.debug("Could not connect", err);
    });
    callback(socket);
  });
};
```

This is invoked from `config/bootstrap.js` as follows:

```
Watcher.connect(function(socket){
  sails.log.debug("Connected watcher to relay with socket", socket);
});
```

On the Express side my server `relay.js` is as simple as:

```
var app = require('express')(),
    http = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(http),
    port = process.env.RELAY_PORT || 8000;

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var response = {message: "some response"}; // to be implemented.
  res.json(response);
});

http.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Relay listening on port " + port);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log("Connection opened", socket);
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log("Socket disconnected");
  });
});
```

When I run `node relay` it dutifully reports

```
Relay listening on port 8000
```

When I `sails lift` my other server it dutifully reports

```
will connect socket to http://localhost:8000 with Socket.io-client version 0.9.16
```

But I never see an actual connection.

If I point a browser at `localhost:8000` I get the `{"message":"some response"}` `JSON` response I expect.

Why isn't my relay server accepting a connection from my socker.io-client app?

Comment: What version of socket.io are you using? 1.0 introduced some breaking changes, which aren't backwards-compatible with 0.9.*.

Comment: Excellent point.  Sails is using socket.io version 0.9.14 - my express app is using socket.io 1.x - I'll dive back in and sync those.

Comment: Okay downgraded my express server to 0.9.14 but it's still not working.  I'll keep digging though.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is probably that you're trying to re-use the
`socket.io-client` from inside of Sails.  In general, if you're `require()`-ing dependencies of Sails directly in your project, you're heading in the wrong direction.  In this case, `socket.io-client` caches configurations and connections, so your `require` isn't getting a fresh copy.

Instead, do

```
npm install socket.io-client@~0.9.16 --save
```

in your project and require with

```
var client = require('socket.io-client');
```

that'll give you a fresh copy of the socket client to work with, and avoid any conflicts with the Sails core's version.

Comment: Sweet, thanks.  Since I am not relying on Sails' socket.io now I am free to use 1.x of both client and server - all working a treat now.

Comment: Geting `Transport unknown` message from server when connecting @DaveSag